# [TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, pdfjs-dist

My version of pdfjs-dist:  `"pdfjs-dist": "^2.4.456"`
This is import my code:

```
import PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist'
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'
```

and when I call :

```
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker
this.loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument({ data: self.pdfData })
```

It return this error: **[TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined]**

### And I try to console this: `PDFJS`, it return `undefinded`

So when I try this solution in the internet, I add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

in my `index.html` and
`add var PDFJS = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];`

Then it works perfectly...But I dont know why the first approach doesn't work for me...And I do not want use this from CDN because I think it's not stable for my project.
So could you guys give me a point what I missed here? I tried to look around in `node-modules` to figure out but I still do not why i can't `import PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist'`;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I SOLVED MY PROBLEM**
I do not know if it is the root of problem or not, but I just simple change from
`import PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist'` to `import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist'` , and it work perfectly.

Comment: The reason is they don't have `export default` so you cannot use `import PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist'`.

Answer (score 0):

// It will work Now use this

import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = //unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js;

Answer (score 0):

It's working public direct path

```
import { getDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist';
import { GlobalWorkerOptions } from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';
GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = window.location.origin + '/pdfjs/pdf.worker.min.js';
```

and add pdfjs/pdf.worker.min.js in public

[image]